# Transforming PHP code to JQuery Ajax call

Tags: php, json

I need to make an JQuery AJAX request that have the same function as below PHP code.

Question:

**How can i pass PHP variables(merchantId) to AJAX?**

**What do i do with success function?**

PHP Code:

```
    <form method="get" action="http://www.example.com/payments/paymentStore.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="<?php=$merchantid?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay" name="PayKZM">
    </form>
```

Ajax Call

```
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="right">

<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" id="button-confirm" class="button" />
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-confirm').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.example.com/payments/paymentStore.html',
        data: "merchantId="+$merchantId,
        success: function() {
            location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
        }       
    });
});
//--></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, you just need to get the value from the hidden input field:

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="merchantId" name="merchantId" value="<?php=$merchantid?>">
```

JS:

```
$('#button-confirm').bind('click', function() {
    var merchant_id = $('#merchantId').val();
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.example.com/payments/paymentStore.html',
        data: "merchantId="+merchant_id,
        success: function() {
            location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
        }       
    });
});
```

Of course, looking at the fact that you pass the location to the JS section through a PHP string you could simply do

```
...
data: "merchantId='<?php echo $merchantId; ?>'",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <div class="buttons">
  <div class="right">

 <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" 
   id="button-confirm" class="button" onclick='functionname(".$merchantid.")' />
 </div>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
  public functionname(merchan_id) {
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/payments/paymentStore.html',
    data: "merchantId="+merchan_id,
    success: function() {
        location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
    }       
});
});
 </script>
```

Comment: He is already using a perfectly good click handler on the button. Why would you want him to switch to an ugly onClick?